# Gensim Summarizer throws MemoryError, Any Solution?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am trying to generate the summary of a large text file using Gensim Summarizer. 
I am getting memory error. Have been facing this issue since sometime, any help
would be really appreciated. feel free to ask for more details.

```
from gensim.summarization.summarizer import summarize

file_read =open("xxxxx.txt",'r')
Content= file_read.read()


def Summary_gen(content):
    print(len(Content))
    summary_r=summarize(Content,ratio=0.02)
    print(summary_r)


Summary_gen(Content)
```

The length of the document is:

```
365042
```

Error messsage:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a91bd71076d1> in <module>()
     10 
     11 
---> 12 Summary_gen(Content)

<ipython-input-6-a91bd71076d1> in Summary_gen(content)
      6 def Summary_gen(content):
      7     print(len(Content))
----> 8     summary_r=summarize(Content,ratio=0.02)
      9     print(summary_r)
     10 

c:\python3.6\lib\site-packages\gensim\summarization\summarizer.py in summarize(text, ratio, word_count, split)
    428     corpus = _build_corpus(sentences)
    429 
--> 430     most_important_docs = summarize_corpus(corpus, ratio=ratio if word_count is None else 1)
    431 
    432     # If couldn't get important docs, the algorithm ends.

c:\python3.6\lib\site-packages\gensim\summarization\summarizer.py in summarize_corpus(corpus, ratio)
    367         return []
    368 
--> 369     pagerank_scores = _pagerank(graph)
    370 
    371     hashable_corpus.sort(key=lambda doc: pagerank_scores.get(doc, 0), reverse=True)

c:\python3.6\lib\site-packages\gensim\summarization\pagerank_weighted.py in pagerank_weighted(graph, damping)
     57 
     58     """
---> 59     adjacency_matrix = build_adjacency_matrix(graph)
     60     probability_matrix = build_probability_matrix(graph)
     61 

c:\python3.6\lib\site-packages\gensim\summarization\pagerank_weighted.py in build_adjacency_matrix(graph)
     92         neighbors_sum = sum(graph.edge_weight((current_node, neighbor)) for neighbor in graph.neighbors(current_node))
     93         for j in xrange(length):
---> 94             edge_weight = float(graph.edge_weight((current_node, nodes[j])))
     95             if i != j and edge_weight != 0.0:
     96                 row.append(i)

c:\python3.6\lib\site-packages\gensim\summarization\graph.py in edge_weight(self, edge)
    255 
    256         """
--> 257         return self.get_edge_properties(edge).setdefault(self.WEIGHT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, self.DEFAULT_WEIGHT)
    258 
    259     def neighbors(self, node):

c:\python3.6\lib\site-packages\gensim\summarization\graph.py in get_edge_properties(self, edge)
    404 
    405         """
--> 406         return self.edge_properties.setdefault(edge, {})
    407 
    408     def add_edge_attributes(self, edge, attrs):

MemoryError:
```

I have tried looking up for this error on the internet, but, couldn't find a workable solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, it looks like the code builds an adjacency matrix

`---> 59     adjacency_matrix = build_adjacency_matrix(graph)`

This probably tries to create a huge adjacency matrix with your `365042` documents which cannot fit in your memory(i.e., RAM).

You could try:

1. Reducing the document size to fewer files (maybe start with 10000)
   and check if it works
2. Try running it on a system with more RAM

Comment: I only wanted to run it on big documents. I tried textrank summarizer method of Sumy earlier on the same system and it was able to calculate the summary. I think it is the limitation of Gensim then. I just wanted to know if there was a way I can find the summary using Gensim only on documents this big.

Comment: I might be wrong. Please don't take my word for it. I suggest you post the question on the gensim mailing list where the developer can reply directly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `word_count` argument instead of `ratio`?

If the above still doesn't solve the problem, then that's because of `gensim`'s implementation limitations. The only way to use `gensim` if you still OOM errors is to split documents. That also will speed up your solution (and if the document is really big, it shouldn't be a problem anyway).

#### What's the problem with `summarize`:

`gensim`'s `summarizer` uses TextRank by default, an algorithm that uses PageRank. In `gensim` it is  unfortunately implemented [using a Python list of PageRank graph nodes](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/summarization/pagerank_weighted.py#L86), so it may fail if your graph is too big.

BTW is the document length measured in words, or characters?

Comment: I think the word_count would produce the same error, because it just changes the length of summary, not the way Gensim is calculating the most important sentences. The Document length is measured in Characters, number of words in the document is around 60,000 words. Is there a efficient way that the document can be split into smaller parts and then a summary can be calculated from them. There is a method called summarize_corpus, is there any way it can be used here?

Comment: I meant that you should try out low `word_count` and see what happens. By splitting I meant just splitting input by half. Unfortunately your code doesn't define neither `Content` or `content` so I have no idea whether it is a string or something else.

Comment: Low `word_count` is throwing the same error. I have edited the code now, could you have a look?